# Union boolean glitch with non destructive modeling

Tags: modifiers

I trying to merge two objects but this happend when i bool union. Please help me fix that!
[image]

Comment: Put the other object in a new collection and disable that collection. Or hide it in the viewport *and* render.

Comment: The other object is still there so they're "Z-fighting" because they overlap now. Do what Geri says, but be aware that hiding an object in the viewport won't remove it from the render, for that you need to disable it, but that's another question.

Comment: @Kuboå "Or hide it in viewport **_and_ render**" (Geri)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ah, and I was wondering why Geri would suggest that OP render an image after hiding the object in the viewport ("hide, and then render"). Shouldn't comment while sleepy.